# how to disable wifi 5G Channel 100~165 (band 3 and band 4) in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have a question, regarding the Intel wifi 9260 module using in windows 10
I am doing Tunisia compliance process, wifi 5G band 3 and band4  (channel 100~165) are not allowed use in Tunisia.  I already set windows 10 regional in Tunisia (re-install OS) . but still doesn't work.
does any one have any information can share to me ?

thank you

Comment: RF Compliance is typically the responsibility of the access point.  How are you determining this isn’t happening exactly?

Comment: thank you,  I also got same replied from my friend,this responsibility is from AP. but the thing is Tunisia use an international version AP to check the tablet , the tablet wifi5G band 3 and 4 are still work.. , I did another project , it use different wifi module , the OS is Android. it can be set country code to pass the test (disable band 3 and 4),  so I am thinking, is any thing I missed in windows 10 setting,

Comment: Some cards can disable bands within the advanced section of the drivers (device manager). It will depend on the wireless card and OS drivers for these settings. Generally what I have seen, the windows database drivers do not have all of the manufacturer specific features for cards. If you don't find these settings under the card in device manager.. try installing the drivers from the manufacturer, they are usually full feature.